# Solving ODE $x' = \lambda x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently studying continuous dependence ODE theory, and there's one example given in our lecture notes, where I am confused how to solve it.

The equation is: $\displaystyle x' = \lambda~x^2$ and furthermore there's a function defined as $\displaystyle f(t,x,\lambda) = \lambda~x^2$

Can anybody go with me through the steps to find the explicit solution in terms of $ \displaystyle t, t_0, x_0$ and $ \displaystyle \lambda$? I tried to solve the equation as a separable equation, but I wouldn't get to a satisfying result.

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have mentioned that!

Comment: What is your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\lambda x^2,$ assuming $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$\dfrac{dx}{x^2}=\lambda dt$. Integrating both sides, we get $\int\dfrac{dx}{x^2}=\lambda \int dt$.

This gives $-\dfrac{1}{x}=\lambda t +c$ as the answer.

If its further given that $x(t_0)=x_0$ ($x_0\ne 0$), then applying the condition on the solution we get,

$-\dfrac{1}{x_0}-\lambda t_0=c$. So the final solution becomes

$-\dfrac{1}{x}=\lambda t -\dfrac{1}{x_0}-\lambda t_0$. Simplify this to get a better expression.

Comment: You are missing the trivial solution $x=0$.

Comment: @Reasoner So you supposed in your answer that $x$ is not the zero function ? Ok then, what allows you nevertheless to divide by $x(t)$ ? Because $x$ can not be the zero solution and still have a zero somewhere. Can you prove that it is not the case please ?